# '%s' % 'somestring'

Tags: python, django

Here are a couple of examples taken from [django-basic-apps](http://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps/):

```
# self.title is a unicode string already
def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title

# 'q' is a string
search_term = '%s' % request.GET['q']
```

What's the point of this string formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a habit of mine. In these cases it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it doesn't look sensible, but it does have the benefit of forcing the result to be a string (or unicode string), rather than whatever it might have been from before. Another way to do the same thing might be to call `str` on the format argument (or unicode).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off asking [Nathan Borror](http://github.com/nathanborror), the author. It may just be a personal style.

Django does use proxy objects for strings in some cases though, so it may be to force them to "actual" strings. I believe these proxies are for i18n/l10n purposes (don't quote me on that, could also be to avoid db lookups until needed, or a number of other reasons).

Comment: In those two cases they would already be strings. CharacterFields return unicodes, and RequestDicts return strs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the author is used to strictly typed languages and he misses it in python and this is his way to make python more strictly typed than it is.

Here - to make the types of input/output parameters clear only for the *reader* because provided all is working as expected it is just useless for the *python* itself.

Comment: Useless for the interpreter, but that's just me being picky.

Comment: Well, Python does have a compiler and an interpreter, but this is a runtime thing so it's the interpreter that wouldn't care.

Comment: My point is that provided `isinstance(x,unicode)` two expressions `x` and `u'%s' % x` are semantically equivalent. Meanwhile they are different syntactically and processed differently (generate different bytecode).

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: Maybe this is done with possible future implementations in mind?  self.title and request.GET[…] are currently already of the desired type, but implementation details might change in the future, and they might stop being a unicode string or a string.

Now, I would have used str() and unicode(), though…